# non-static method getContentPane() cannot be referenced from a static context error in java swing

Tags: java, swing

non-static method getContentPane() cannot be referenced from a static context error in java swing

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Studentlogin extends JFrame{
   public static void main(String[] args) {

    Container c = getContentPane();

    setTitle(" Staff Signin ");
    setSize( 400 , 300);
    setLayout(new FlowLayout());    
    setVisible(true);
    setLayout(null);

    JLabel tun = new JLabel("UserName");
    tun.setBounds(10,10,140,25);
    c.add(sun);

    JTextField tuname = new JTextField(10);
    tuname.setToolTipText("Enter your StaffId ");
    tuname.setBounds(145,10,200,25);
    c.add(tuname);

    JLabel tpw = new JLabel("PassWord");
    tpw.setBounds(10,50,140,25);
    c.add(tpw); 

    JPasswordField tpword = new JPasswordField(10);
    tpword.setEchoChar('*');
    tpword.setBounds(145,50,200,25);
    c.add(tpword);
}
}
```

while compiling this i get this type of error can anyone find me what is wrong with this code because i can execute this same type format of code in actionlistrener segment

```
Studentlogin.java:9: error: non-static method getContentPane() cannot be referen
ced from a static context
                Container c = getContentPane();
                              ^
Studentlogin.java:11: error: non-static method setTitle(String) cannot be refere
nced from a static context
                setTitle(" Staff Signin ");
                ^
Studentlogin.java:12: error: non-static method setSize(int,int) cannot be refere
nced from a static context
                setSize( 400 , 300);
                ^
```

Comment: That error message is almost an answer. Please read again and again.

Comment: why do you have tried it from the main method..the jFrame must me child thread of main thread..

Comment: That's right you can not call any non-static method from a static method.

Comment: You cannot call non-static methods from a static method, because they simply don't exist. Non-static methods only exist when called on an object. You need to do what you are trying to do in the constructor (for starters) or in a method of the object and then create the object/call the method in the main

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to go from a static to a non-static context. The easiest way is to create an instance of your class, and call a method, e.g. `go`.

```
public class Studentlogin extends JFrame{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Studentlogin().go();
    }

    private void go() {
        Container c = getContentPane();

        setTitle(" Staff Signin ");
        setSize( 400 , 300);
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        setVisible(true);
        setLayout(null);

        JLabel tun = new JLabel("UserName");
        tun.setBounds(10,10,140,25);
        c.add(sun);

        JTextField tuname = new JTextField(10);
        tuname.setToolTipText("Enter your StaffId ");
        tuname.setBounds(145,10,200,25);
        c.add(tuname);

        JLabel tpw = new JLabel("PassWord");
        tpw.setBounds(10,50,140,25);
        c.add(tpw);

        JPasswordField tpword = new JPasswordField(10);
        tpword.setEchoChar('*');
        tpword.setBounds(145,50,200,25);
        c.add(tpword);
    }

}
```

Comment: K. Thanks for your replies

Comment: You're welcome. Remember to please accept the answer (green tick) if you find it useful.

Comment: PS: you also have a typo here: `c.add(sun);`